# regexp that selects only the capital letter from another regexp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this type of text:

```
!D este caro
1 C este descgiderea
C1 este alta deschidere
Deschiderea de 1C este cu
2C
2D
3 D
1NT
2D
123456P
```

This easy regexp:

```
/([0-9][CDHS])/g
```

selects "1C","2C","2D","2D" (a digit immediately followed by [CDHS], anywhere in the text) .

What I want is to select only the letter from the sequences above (from "1C" -> only C, from "2D" only D, and so on...). How do I do that with a regexp?

le : While Bolo's method is indeed working in RegExr , in Jquery it appears it doesn't :(

Here's the code :

```
$(document).ready(function()
      {
                 var de_inlocuit = [/!C/gi, /!D/gi,/!H/gi,/!S/gi,/(?<=[0-9])[CDHS]/g];
       var replace = ['<img src="/sites/default/files/c.gif"/>', '<img src="/sites/default/files/d.gif"/>','<img src="/sites/default/files/h.gif"/>','<img src="/sites/default/files/s.gif"/>','test' ];
       //<img src="/sites/default/files/c.gif"/>
      var i=0;
      for (i=0; i < de_inlocuit.length; i++)
       {
        $('body table tr td').replaceText( de_inlocuit[i], replace[i] );
       } 

      });
```

The behavior is normal if I remove `/(?<=[0-9])[CDHS]/g` , but since it was inserted into the code it doesn't even replace the other (surely) working regexp .

Comment: And my guess is bridge on BBO :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use capturing groups, like with this regex:

```
/([0-9])([CDHS])/g
```

...just insert the appropriately numbered group reference into the replacement string, for example:

```
"rank=$1, suit=$2"
```

JavaScript regexes do not support lookbehinds, so that approach won't work.  The reason @Bolo's solution works in RegExr is because that's a *Flex* application.  Try it in a JavaScript-powered tester like [this one](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm) and you'll get more relevant results.

Adobe advertises its ActionScript regexes as being compatible with JavaScript's, with an identical list of supported features, but they're actually much more powerful, being powered by the [PCRE library](http://www.pcre.org/).  So take care to use a *JavaScript* tester to test your JS regexes, not a Flex tool like RegExr or [RyanSwanson.com](http://ryanswanson.com/regexp/#start).

Answer (score 1):

Take the digit off the capture group:

```
/[0-9]([CDHS])/g
```

By the way the original pattern doesn't match strings that have a space in between the letter and the digit. You can allow an optional space with:

```
/[0-9]\s*([CDHS])/g
```

Comment: You'll also have to make sure to select the first capture group, not the zeroth (entire string).

Comment: @Aillyn - I don't want any space between the letter and the digit . English is by default

Comment: @andrei I meant programming language

Comment: @Aillyn , oups , obviously :D I'm trying to use this in a jquery script (in replacetext function actually)

Answer (score 0):

First option: use a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/(?<=[0-9])[CDHS]/g
```

Second option: use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (as mentioned in Aillyn's answer):

```
/[0-9]([CDHS])/g
```

In the second case, however, you have to take the contents of the 1<sup>st</sup> capturing group, instead of the whole match (i.e., group #1 instead of group #0).  How to do it depends on the programming language that you're using.

Comment: I don't think it makes a lot of sense to use zero-width assertions in this case, but if it works... I am just curious why the second option didn't work.

Comment: Well I don't really know how to display only the 1st capturing group instead of the whole match . I'm using this regexp in a jquery script (replacetext function actually) .


Testing with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ , /[0-9]([CDHS])/g doesn't work on its own . I would be glad if someone explained to me how to select only the first group

Comment: @Aillyn I don't like to overuse zero-width assertions either, but OTOH it may be more difficult to handle capturing groups in certain programming languages / environments.

Comment: @andrei I've never used jquery, but my first guess is: try `\1` as the replacement string.